# Material-ui collapse with horizontal orientation does not work like expected

Tags: material-ui

i am building an app targeted to tablet devices,
basically the main layout is :
[image]

Where the central area have three columns: navigation, header list, items details.

I want to give the user the possibility to horizontal collapse the header list
so then items details will expand.

Setting the prop orientation={'horizontal'}, it dont change the behaviour and keep collapsing in vertical.

Desired:

[image]

Reality:

[image]

Reading the code
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/cce45deec3125c1f0dd6c1c74616b5e63b027026/packages/material-ui/src/Collapse/Collapse.js

Show that orientation can be horizontal:

```
orientation: PropTypes.oneOf(['horizontal', 'vertical']),
```

Even there is a collapsedHeight, but not a collapsedWidth

```
function CollapsePanel(props) {
  const [collapsed, setCollapse] = React.useState(true);//
  //orientation: PropTypes.oneOf(['horizontal', 'vertical']),  
  return (
           <Collapse in={collapsed} collapsedHeight={0} orientation={'horizontal'} >           
           <div style={{border:'5px solid blue',
                       display:"flex",flexDirection: "column", alignItems:"center",                      
                       minWidth:'180px',  alignItems:"stretch", height:'calc(100vh - 40px)',}} > 
           <IconButton onClick={ ()=>setCollapse(!collapsed)}><ChevronLeftIcon/> Collapse</IconButton>
           <div style={{display:"flex",flexDirection: "column", alignItems:"center", justifyContent: "space-around", flexGrow:'1', }} > 
           Headers List            
           </div>   
           </div>   
           </Collapse>             
    )
};
```

The package version is:
npm list --depth=0

@material-ui/core@4.11.3

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

4.11.3 doesn't have the orientation prop:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.3/packages/material-ui/src/Collapse/Collapse.js

The link in your question points to the v5-alpha branch where orientation was added.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, now understand what this cce45deec3125c1f0dd6c1c74616b5e63b027026 means. Do you know another way to implement this behaviour ?

Comment: You could wrap the collapse component to implement the behavior from v5-alpha, i.e. overwrite the styles and add a prop for horizontal orientation.